# JS cancelAnimationFrame syntax

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

This may be really easy question but i just started playing with request animation frame and i need some guidance. I found on the internet that the safest (in terms of browser compatibility) syntax for request animation frame is this code:

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
                function(callback, element) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
    })();
```

and then call it like this: `requestAnimFrame( protect );`

the question is how to build cancel animation frame syntax to perfectly align with the above one. ( should cancel all above prefix starters and set timeout in case of fallback).

Thank you for the answers ;)

**---EDIT---**

I just found this article [>click me<](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Solution presented in the article only includes vendors `webkit` and `moz` as they claim that `2013.03.06: No more [ms] or [o] prefixes neccessary. Removed.` I dont know now if the solution is complete and can be used today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love caniuse.com for these kind of things. Check out:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe

You could click Show All and see all of the browser versions and what kind of requestAnimationFrame they support(prefixes included).

But I think it's pretty safe just to use `requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame`. Unless you really really really need to support browsers like IE9 or Safari 6 you don't need to shim this.

Comment: i need support for ie9 and such unfortunetely

Comment: In that case the polyfill from the article is your best bet(https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671), since it also polyfills cancelAnimationFrame. Note that you'll have shitty performance in IE9.